# codeigniter german characters in database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have set this collation in database.php and same in database:
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_german2_ci';

When i insert a german characters it is saved in database as:

```
Three Burials - Die drei Begr?bnisse des Melquiades Estrada
```

But it should be:

```
Three Burials - Die drei Begräbnisse des Melquiades Estrada
```

my query:

```
$this->db->insert('table',array('title' => $this->input->post('title')));
```

How can i solve this issue? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set collation everywhere to `utf8`, `utf8_general_ci` as well as your page encoding and charset.

There is practically no reason to use anything else, otherwise than maniacally optimizing storage efficiency.

Comment: Thx, i updated db and file with "utf8_general_ci" but now it is inserting half title "Three Burials - Die drei Begr"

Comment: What is the length value of your column? Have you updated your database collation as well as table collation (they might be different) and collation in your CodeIgniter database config file? Also, try running this right after inserting: `die($this->db->last_query());` see what exactly is being inserted

Comment: i used query "ALTER TABLE  `movies` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" , my column is 1000 character long varchar(1000) utf8_general_ci, and in config $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Comment: i run last_query() and it is displaying correct title "'Three Burials - Die drei Begräbnisse des Melquiades Estrada'" but does not insert complete in database so it cut it after ä

Comment: Try running `$your_string = utf8_encode($your_string);` before inserting into the database

Comment: Wait a moment, there should be a better way :) Doing some research

Comment: Could you please tell me your PHP version?

Comment: @Dshah pretty strange, as I can run `$this->db->insert('groups', array('name' => 'test', 'description' => 'Three Burials - Die drei Begräbnisse des Melquiades Estrada'));` in my projects without running `utf8_encode()` and it inserts data just fine. In my `database.php` config file I have `$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';`. I think you have missed setting this somewhere, other than that, I just can't replicate your problem to help you..

Comment: its alright , thank you for your efforts i will just use utf8_encode()..Thanks again.